# exporting variables to csv using casperjs

Tags: javascript, variables, csv, casperjs

I have the piece of code which will click a link, scrape data, close the link and then repeat. It works great. However, I'm trying to concatenate the `lbdes` variable to the `longdescription` variable so I can export the `longdescription` variable into a csv. When I run the code below nothing happens, no errors, just a blank command prompt comes up like it ran fine.

```
var longdescription = "";


function scheduleScrapeAndClose(){
    casper.waitUntilVisible(x('//*[@id="product-infoform"]'));
    casper.wait(5000, function(){
        lbdes = casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="product_overview"]'));
        longdescription += lbdes;
        casper.click(x('//*[@id="product-infocloser"]'));
    });
    casper.waitWhileVisible(x('//*[@id="product_overview"]'));
}

casper.then(function(){
    var buttonNumber = casper.getElementsInfo(".button.small.orange").length;
    for(var i = 0; i < buttonNumber; i++) {
        //casper.thenClick('.search-product-image');
        casper.thenClick(x("(//*[contains(@class,'button') and contains(@class,'small') and     contains(@class,'orange')])["+(i+1)+"]"));
        scheduleScrapeAndClose();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the question? What do you expect when you initialize `longdescription` with an empty string and immediately print it. You need to print something after you do the processing. Keep in mind that it should be inside of a step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasnt thinking -- added a function after the above code which then called the variable and it worked properly.